# Executing batch file from Python causes infinite loop

Tags: python, batch-file

I have this python code:

```
import os
os.system("cleanup.bat")
```

and this is my cleanup.bat file:

```
sc delete service1
sc delete service2

reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Key1" /f
reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Key2" /f

EXIT
```

However, when I run my python code, my batch file loops infinitely. What is causing this?

Comment: We need to see more of the python code. The problem isn't in those two lines.

Comment: Those are the only two lines of code I have.
I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Why write those two lines of code?  Why not just run `cleanup.bat`?

Comment: I tried exactly your Python script, also on 2.7 and Windows, and a similar batch file, and had no loop. How are you running the python code?

Comment: I do other stuff, but I commented out the everything else to test it.
I am running the code from command prompt by doing "Python code.py"

Comment: Try making a new Python file with just those two lines and running it the same way. How do you know the batch file is looping indefinitely? Is there any output? Does Python exit?

Comment: I've done that too and the same thing still happens. The batch file loops infinitely because in the command prompt I see the commands executing and I see them loop. I do not think python exits. When I open up task manager, I actually see new python processes get created each time there is a "loop". So I added 'sys.exit' at the end of the python script and I still get new python processes.

Comment: So i modified the batch file. It no longer loops if the batch file looks like this:  


    `sc delete service1  

    sc delete service2  
  
    EXIT`

Edit: I can't get this to format correctly

Comment: @mkdz:  As this information may be useful to someone answering the question who may not read the comments, may I suggest you put this later information into an edit to your question?  BTW, you won't be able to format the code correctly as you don't have the same  capabilities in comments as you do in questions & answers.

Comment: Two troubleshooting thoughts: a) not that this should matter, but put the 'sc delete', 1st 'reg delete' and 2nd 'reg delete' in separate .bat files and call them in sequence. b) you don't have any antivirus or security tool preventing you editing the registry? Try the 'reg delete' commands from the command-line, do they succeed?

Answer (score 0):

On my system, there already is a cleanup.bat in system32. It looks like a leftover of some installation.

Do not rely on the path nor the file extension association. A BAT file is not executable, it is interpreted by cmd.exe.

Change your Python code to this

```
import os
os.system("cmd.exe /c .\\cleanup.bat")
```

And run it without relying on file extension association, like this

```
python cleanup.py
```